# Tangent Space Coincides with Null Space of Jacobian When Full Rank

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization, manifolds, implicit-function-theorem

This is for an optimization class, but I think what I am trying to prove is erring towards differential geometry, if that tag is inappropriate please remove it. My professor left this claim asserted but not proven, I would like to prove it. I found a lower dimensional case [here](http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~fjones/chap5.pdf) on page 24 that I am trying to adapt.

Here is the background, and the problem.

Let $$g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m,$$ $$g(\mathbf{x}) = [ g_1(\mathbf{x}), \dots , g_m(\mathbf{x})]^{T}$$ where $n \geq m$ and each $g_i$ is a $C^{1}$ map $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Set $k$ to be the codim $n-m$. Define $S$ to be the zero locus of $g$ and for $\mathbf{x}_0 \in S$ define the tangent space $T_{\mathbf{x}_0}S$ to be the set of vectors $\mathbf{v}$ such that there exists a curve $\gamma(t) \subset S$ with $\gamma(0) = \mathbf{x}_0$ and $\gamma'(0) = \mathbf{v}$. Let $Dg(\mathbf{x}_0)$ denote the $m$ x $n$ Jacobian of $g$ at $\mathbf{x}_0$ and assume it has full rank. I would like to prove that

> $$\mathrm{Nul}(Dg(\mathbf{x}_0)) \subseteq T_{\mathbf{x}_0} S.$$

Here is what I have so far (almost entirely adapted from the link provided above). Suppose $\mathbf{v} \in \mathrm{Nul}(Dg(\mathbf{x}_0))$, then in particular $\nabla g_i(\mathbf{x}_0) \cdot \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$ and all of the $\nabla g_i(\mathbf{x}_0)$ are linearly independent. After a suitable reordering of the variables, we can apply the Implicit Function Theorem  (exactly as stated on the wiki page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), reordering the variables so that $m$ x $m$ matrix is invertible, invoking the full rank of the Jacobian). Now denote the point $\mathbf{x}_0 = (x_1,\dots,x_k,y_1,\dots,y_m)$. Let $\mathbf{a} = (x_1,\dots,x_k)$ and $\mathbf{b} = (y_1, \dots, y_k)$. By invoking the IFT we have some open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^k$, $\mathbf{a} \in U$, and the existence of a $C^{1}$ map $\phi \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\phi(\mathbf{a}) = \mathbf{b}$ and $g(\mathbf{x},\phi(\mathbf{x}) = 0$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in U$.

I am attempting to use all of the above to start building a parameterization $\gamma(t)$, but this is where I am stuck. I would like to define $\gamma_i(t) = x_i + v_i t$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$. Since $U$ is open I should be able to choose $\epsilon$ sufficiently small so that, at least for these first $k$ coordinates $\gamma$ stays in $S$ for $t \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$. But I don't know how to finish the next $m$ entries of $\gamma$. My assumption is that when the parameterization works out, the derivative portion of the Implicit Function Theorem combined with my hypothesis will allow me to say $\gamma'(0) = \mathbf{v}$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $T_{x_0} S \subset \mathrm{Nul}(Dg(x_0))$. This follows since given $v \in T_{x_0}S$, we can consider a curve $\gamma \subset S$ such that $\gamma(0)=x_0$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$. Thus, by the chain rule,
$$ (g \circ \gamma)'(0)=Dg(x_0) \cdot \gamma'(0)=Dg(x_0) \cdot v.$$
Since the left side is obviously zero as $g$ is constant along $\gamma$, it follows that $v$ is in the kernel of $Dg(x_0)$. But $T_{x_0}S$ has dimension $n-m$, and so thus $\mathrm{Nul}(Dg(x_0))$ by the rank-nullity theorem. Thus, both must coincide.

Comment: $T_{x_0} S  \subseteq \mathrm{Nul}$ is the containment that was proven in class today, but why do we know that $\mathrm{dim}T_{x_0} S$ is $n-m$ ? My original thought was to do exactly this, and apply a dimension count to get equality but I didn't see why the dimension of the tangent space had to be $n-m$, so I began trying to prove it directly..

Comment: @PrinceM That is where the implicit function theorem/inverse function theorem enters. The relevant theorem is that the pre-image of a regular value of a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a smooth submanifold of dimension $n-m$. One can see this quite directly by using an intermediate result called the "local form of submersions", but there are other (equivalent) means. One way or the other, this theorem surely has been mentioned or referenced in class and you are probably free to use it. What you are attempting is essentially a reproof of this.

Comment: It unfortunately hasn't. This class I am in is very elementary optimization and is brushing past all the good stuff. Students weren't expected to even prove this question I am working on. Does this theorem have a name so I can look into it?

Comment: Does the submanifold having dimension $n-m$ imply that the tangent space has dimension $n-m$ as a vector space?

Comment: @PrinceM You can continue on your proof then. Take $\Psi(x)=(x,\phi(x))$ and show that $T_{x_0}S=D\Psi(a)(\mathbb{R}^k)$, thus getting the dimension conclusion (conclude that $D\Psi(a)$ is injective before, but this is simple). That $D\Psi(a)(\mathbb{R}^k) \subset T_{x_0}(S)$ follows from the chain rule, and that  $T_{x_0}(S) \subset D\Psi(a)(\mathbb{R}^k)$ follows from the fact that for a curve $\gamma \subset S,$ we have that $\Psi \circ \pi \circ \gamma= \gamma$, and thus $D\Psi(a)\cdot (\pi \circ \gamma)'(0)=\gamma'(0)$.

Comment: @PrinceM Glad that I could be helpful! With regards to the theorem I mentioned, it usually goes through variations of the name "regular value theorem" or "preimage theorem".